# Localize variable for multiple Shortcodes

Tags: jquery, shortcode, wp-localize-script

I have this code for flexslider Shortcode

```
add_shortcode('flexslider', function($atts){
global $post;
$ids = explode(',', $atts[ids]);

$uniqid = uniqid();
wp_enqueue_script( 'shortcode_flexslider');
wp_localize_script( 'shortcode_flexslider', 'slider', array('id' => $uniqid)); 

foreach( $ids as $id ) {
    $imgLinks       = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, large);
    $imgThumb       = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, thumbnail);

    $slider     .= '<li><img src="'.$imgLinks[0].'">'.$imgCaptionContent.'</li>';
    $carousel   .= '<li><img src="'.$imgThumb[0].'"></li>'; 
}
$structure ='<div id="slider'.$uniqid.'" class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">'
            .$slider.
            '</ul></div>'.

            '<div id="carousel'.$uniqid.'" class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">'
            .$carousel.
            '</ul></div>';   
});
```

I put `uniqid` for slider and carousel ids to can put more one flexslider Shortcode in the same post and I localize the `uniqid` to shortcode_flexslider JS file to find slider and carousel ids

```
$('#carousel'+slider.id).flexslider({
  //
   asNavFor: '#slider'+slider.id
  //
});

$('#slider'+slider.id).flexslider({
 //
  sync: '#carousel'+slider.id
//
});
```

The problem is when I put more one flexslider Shortcode in the same post the localized variable slider.id get the last flexslider Shortcode uniqid , so the last flexslider Shortcode is only that works ,how i can pass all flexslider Shortcode `uniqid` not just the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ploblem is that `wp_localize_script` print to the html markup a javascript object similar to:

```
var slider = {"id":"a_unique_id_here"};
```

if you call it more times, e.g. using more shortcodes in same page, whati is printend in html markup is

```
var slider = {"id":"a_unique_id_here"};
var slider = {"id":"another_unique_id_here"};
var slider = {"id":"third_unique_id_here"};
```

so you are overwriting again and again the same variable.

You need this sort of thing, you should transform the output in something like this:

```
var slider_ddAsfe2ser = {"id":"a_unique_id_here"};
var slider_fsdgffereR = {"id":"another_unique_id_here"};
var slider_d4frfAd1ej = {"id":"third_unique_id_here"};
```

I.E. you have to create an unique named variable as settings object for every shorcode.

How? Something like:

```
add_shortcode('flexslider', function($atts) {
  global $post;
  $ids = explode(',', $atts[ids]);
  $uniqid = uniqid();
  wp_enqueue_script( 'shortcode_flexslider');
  $token = wp_generate_password(32, false, false);
  wp_localize_script( 'shortcode_flexslider', 'slider_' . $token, array('id' => $uniqid));
  foreach( $ids as $id ) {
    // ... your code here ...
  }
  $structure = '<div id="slider' . $uniqid. '" class="flexslider"';
  $structure .= ' data-token="' . $token . '">'; // the token as data attribute
  $structure .= '<ul class="slides">' . $slider . '</ul></div>';
  $structure .= '<div id="carousel' . $uniqid . '" class="flexslider">';
  $structure .= '<ul class="slides">' . $carousel . '</ul></div>'
});
```

After that in your **js**:

```
// cicle all the divs with 'flexslider' class and id that starts with 'slider'
$('div.flexslider[id^="slider"]').each( function() { 
  var $div = $(this); // the sdiv jquery object
  var token = $div.data('token');
  // use the bracket syntax to retrieve the unique named object
  // in the global (window) scope
  var settingObj = window['slider_' + token];
  $div.flexslider({
    //
    sync: '#carousel' + settingObj.id
    //
  });
  $carousel = $( '#carousel' + settingObj.id); // the carousel div jquery object
  $carousel.flexslider({
    //
    asNavFor: '#slider' + settingObj.id
    //
  });
}); // end each cycle
```

Comment: I don't understand what  window[] do ?

Comment: There is a variable like: `slider_dddf1f5fe5225rdf525fs2sf22sdfAsf = { "id":"a_unique_id_here" };`. You have the token part (32 chars after '_'), in a variable: 'token'. So the entire variable name is `'slider_' + token`. With `window['slider_' + token]` you get the value for that variable, because the variable is in the `window` scope (in php something *similar* is `$_GLOBALS['slider_' + $token]`). @MohamedBadawy

Comment: thank you , i also use uniqid() instead wp_generate_password() for variable token,it will be like this slider_dddf1f5fe5225rdf525fs2sf22sdfAsf = { "id":"dddf1f5fe5225rdf525fs2sf22sdfAsf" };

Comment: @MohamedBadawy sure better, once you have already a unique id is not a good idea calculate it again. Normally I don't like `uniqid()` for tokens (In your case I'd used once `wp_generate_password`), but is just an opinion.

Comment: yes i used wp_generate_password ,it's cute :)

Comment: awesome but smart solution. Wish I found it earlier,  had nearly the same but it took my ages to get there.... Thank you @gmazzap

Answer (score 1):

Well...

```
wp_localize_script( 'shortcode_flexslider', 'slider', array('id' => $uniqid)); 
wp_localize_script( 'shortcode_flexslider', 'carousel', array('id' => $uniqid));
```

Or...

```
wp_localize_script( 
  'shortcode_flexslider', 
  'slider', 
  array(
    'sliderid' => $uniqid,
    'carouselid' => $uniquid
  )
);
```

You just need to avoid overwriting the variable, that's all. There are probably other ways to do it, but those two should get you started. I'd prefer the latter.