# Multiple shortcodes only use attributes from one of the shortcodes on custom plugin

Tags: shortcode, wp-localize-script

Created a shortcode, however when multiple shortcodes are used on a page the $atts passed in are only from the last shortcode that was used. What am I doing wrong?

```
public function init(){
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 
        array( $this, 'load_dialog_scripts') );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',
        array( $this, 'load_dialog_styles') );
    add_shortcode( 'post-dialog-button', 
        array( $this ,'post_dialog_func') );
}
public function post_dialog_func( $atts ){

    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'button_image' => 'button image',
        'post_id' => 'some post id',
        'image' => 'post image here',
        'header' => 'post title here',
        'content' => 'post content here',
        'post_footer' => 'post footer info here',
    ), $atts );

    wp_localize_script( 'dialog-popup-script', 'dialog_popup_script', $a );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'dialog-popup-script' );

    $shortcode_button = '<div class="button-dialog-container">DEMO</div>';

    return $shortcode_button;
}
```

I was able to find an in depth answer to this same problem here:
[Localize variable for multiple Shortcodes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114807/localize-variable-for-multiple-shortcodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you're using `wp_localize_script` you're replacing the values inside the `dialog_popup_script` object. If each popup requires different settings, and those settings are set on the shortcode, you might be better off storing the values as data attributes on the div.

Comment: Ah I understand now!  This led me to find an in depth look at a solution.